# Displaying RSS items which have dates 7 days before the first item

Tags: php, rss

I am pulling an RSS Feed from here: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml

In my php I have a $_GET['Date'] function. When a date is typed into the query string, the php displays items published since that date like so:

```
$date1 = $_GET['Date'];
      $date2 = $item->pubDate;
      $publishdate = strtotime($date1);
      $entrydate = strtotime($date2);
      if ($publishdate > $entrydate) {
        continue;
      }

           ?>
```

However, if no date is typed into the query string then all the items from the RSS are shown. Instead of this happening I would like to be able to display items only published 7 days before the first/latest item. I've started below with an if statement, but I'm not to sure on how to reference the first item:

```
<?php
     foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
         if (empty($_GET)) {
```

So, if the first entry in the RSS had a pubDate of: Fri, 19 Apr 2013 14:57:47 GMT, then the php would only show entries published on the 12th Apr 2013 onwwards a.k.a 7 days before the 19th.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml');
//$last  = empty($_GET['Date'])?strtotime("-7 day", strtotime($rss->channel->item[0]->pubDate)):strtotime($_GET['Date']);
if(empty($_GET['Date']))
{
$date7daysago=date('dmY',strtotime("-7 day", strtotime($rss->channel->item[0]->pubDate)));
foreach($rss->channel->item as $item)
{
    if(date('dmY',strtotime($item->pubDate))===$date7daysago)
    {
     echo $item->title.'('.$item->pubDate.')<br>';
    } 
}
exit;
}
```